# Assume the gene for freckles is dominant. A woman with freckles has a son that does not. What would have to be the genotype of the mother?

Tags: human-biology

I need help understanding the question I guess. I have read the chapter in my book but still confused.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please read about how to [ask](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions and take the [tour](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour). This is not a homework forum. If you want an answer, you should show attempts to answer the question yourself, or at least provide some background knowledge on the topic you are asking about. Also provide references and state your questions clearly.

Comment: @AlexDeLarge so why did you then give an answer? From [How do I write a good answer?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`* Providing answers to crap questions like this just encourages more of them, and shows people we don't really care about or enforce the rules.

Comment: @MattDMo: Yes, that would be a never ending dilemma. Actually, i did not say this was a crappy question - I think it would be an appropriate one, if properly stated. Therefore, my comment was meant to be encouraging to improve the question according to the rules. Additionally, I tend to be very indulgent with newcomers - they might not know, they might want to learn. But fact is: they have a question and need help. So I took the 3-5 minutes to answer the question and tried to help T.Seevers out. But, of course, you are right in that this is a bit inconsistent and I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @AlexDeLarge like when dealing with children, consistency is key. (No, I'm not implying that all new users are like children.) "Being indulgent" is exactly the *wrong* attitude to take. Be welcoming, but firmly point them towards the help center and the various meta questions on common topics. If they want to learn, they'll know how. If not, they'll know our reasons. Read *the entire* help center *yourself*, especially what's on- and off-topic, how to write good questions, and how to write good answers. Use [this](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/3275) for some good comment templates.

Comment: @MattDMo: Thanks. As I already said, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mother needs to have a [heterozygous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygosity) genotype. This means that she carries two different alleles at that [gene locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(genetics)). She needs to carry **one** [allele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) for freckles (since she has them herself) and one recessive allele that does not.

Her son **must** have inherited her allele that does **not** cause freckles, otherwise he would have had freckles himself. Accordingly he is probably homozygous for that gene which means that he has two equal alleles, both not causing freckles. Alternatively, he could also be heterozygous but have two different alleles that **both do not** cause freckles (and therefore the allele he inherited from his father is different from both alleles his mother carries).

Comment: So would that mean the mothers genotype is Ff? And that the father doesn't have the same genotype?

Comment: Yes, the mother would be Ff (where f is any allele not causing freckles). No, the father does not **need** to have the same genotype. He **could**, but he could also be Ff*, where f* $\ne$ f but both f* and f alleles do not cause freckles.

Answer (score 0):

Since dominant trumps recessive, the mother, who has freckles, must have at least one F allele. However, since the son doesn't have freckles, and he gets one allele from each parent, it follows that the second allele the mother has is a recessive f.

For extra credit, the father could either have ff or Ff, following the same line of reasoning.

Comment: This only works for biallelic loci which [does not need to be true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele#Multiple_alleles).

Comment: @AlexDeLarge So what's the difference between my answer and yours?

Comment: First, I provide references so that T.Seevers can look these things up, second I account for the possibility that the locus is not biallelic and therefore discuss his genotype, as this might give further insight + account for T.Seevers terminology (genotype) and link this to related and useful concepts (zygosity, gene locus, allele) and third, when I started writing your answer was not there, yet. ;)

Comment: Fourth: you can edit your question accordingly and I will happily delete my answer. :)